# Finding a transformation matrix for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question from the book which says:

Given 2 basis for a vector space $R_n[x]$ (Polynomials) and 2 basis

$B=(1,x,x^2...,x^n)\quad B'=(1,1+x,1+x+x^2,......,1+x+x^2+....x^n)$

Edited: What is the transformation Matrix between B to B'?

The answer is that the matrix looks like this $\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 &0...  &  0&0 \\ 
 0& 1 &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &  1&1  &0 \\ 
 ...&... & ...&...    \\ 
 0&0  &0  &  1&1 
\end{matrix}$

My question is, why? what's the explanatoin? it's not so clear to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exactly your question? It is not clear  (The answer you provided, is the answer to what question?)

Comment: You right. Edited. @DimitarM.H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation matrix doesn't look like the one in your question. Let us express polynomials as row vectors of coefficients with respect to the bases $B$ and $B'.$ More specifically, for a given polynomial $P$ of degree at most $n,$ let $v_B(P)\in \mathbb R^n$ be the row vector of its coefficients with respect to the basis $B$ and let $v_{B'}(P)\in \mathbb R^n$ be the row vector of its coefficients with respect to the basis $B'.$ Then we have
$$
v_B(P) = v_{B'}(P)M\qquad with\qquad M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots &  \\
1 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $M$ has $1$'s on the diagonal and in the lower triangle, and $0$s in the upper triangle. The transformation rule is true because the rows of $M$ are the coefficient vectors of the elements of the basis $B'$ with respect to the basis $B.$

Note that in all of this the ordering of the elements in the bases $B$ and $B'$ is important.